# DECLARAR VARIABLE TIPO FECHA C#

Tags: c#, variables, datetime, datagridview

Requiero de su amable ayuda.

Necesito insertar el contenido de un DataGridView C# en la base de datos, pero no sé cómo declarar la variable tipo fecha puesto que me está arrojando un error.

```
string fechaPermiso = dgvImportarExcel.Rows[cont].Cells["Fecha_Permiso"].Value.ToString();
```

Este es el mensaje que me muestra:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.'*

Le agradezco mucho su ayuda, soy nuevo en este mundo de la programación.

Saludos.

Comment: Todavia no me queda claro tu problema

Comment: Qué valores tiene `fechaPermiso`? Qué tipo de dato exactamente es la columna en la tabla?

Comment: La columna en la tabla es tipo fecha

Comment: Date? DateTime? DateTime2?

Comment: es de tipo Date

Comment: pero escribe un ejemplo de lo que trae fechaPermiso

Comment: El campo Fecha_Permiso en el DataGridView tiene fechas. ej: 2023-01-18 ... esto es lo que debo guardar en la BD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para solucionar este problema, necesitas convertir el contenido de la celda "Fecha_Permiso" de un DataGridView a un tipo de datos fecha. Para ello puedes usar la función DateTime.Parse() de la siguiente manera:

```
string fechaPermiso = DateTime.Parse(dgvImportarExcel.Rows[cont].Cells["Fecha_Permiso"].Value.ToString()).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Esto convertirá la fecha de un formato a otro, para que sea compatible con la base de datos.

Comment: Richard muchas gracias por tu ayuda, con esto solucioné mi problema.